# Resizing Materialize chip component

Tags: materialize

How to resize the Materialize chip component? 
http://materializecss.com/chips.html

I tried changing the CSS of chip, but the round shape distorts.

Comment: Can you please add more details regarding what you were trying already?

Comment: I was simply changing the height and missing the css of img and the border radius. Now it is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just change it's width and height with css.

```
.chip{
   width: 240px;
   height: 80px;
   border-radius: 80px;
   line-height: 80px;
}
.chip img{
   height: 80px;
   width: 80px;
}
```

Standard border-radius is 16px so change this value to the same value as the height this will make the chip round again.

Also the line-height is to make the text centered again.

If you use an image inside the chip you will have to make that bigger aswell.

[Example](https://codepen.io/rikato/pen/QQaMmM)